# Does custom Phonegap/Cordova Plugins written in one native language will work on other?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am writing a custom phone gap plugin to launch camera with my custom view and custom call backs in android.

Do I need to write equivalent iOS code to make my plugin work in iPhone? or the phone gap cloud build service will take care?

If so, how it is doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nope, you have to write native code for each platform you want to use your plugins with.

The only thing phonegap build does is allow to build an app wihout having to install any sdk.